# How to decode the IndirectObject of PDF in Pyhton?

Tags: python, pdf

[The link to PDF](https://fe2023.mahacet.org/2022/2022ENGG_CAP1_CutOff.pdf)

I am trying to extract data from this pdf. But I am getting weird IndirectObject. Please guide me how can I go about this.

```
import PyPDF2
path = 'cutoffs.pdf'
a = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)
pg_1 = a.getPage(0)
pg_1
```

[Outputre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axky5.png)

This is the image of the output.

How can I get the data from this PDF?

Answer (score 0):

```
import PyPDF2

path = 'cutoffs.pdf'
a = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path)
pg_1 = a.getPage(0)
print(pg_1.extractText())
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).